# 2 sets of tabs in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I usually have 2 sets of tabs in google chrome, in 2 windows. 1 for general browsing, and the other for 'work'.

Can I get both windows to auto launch at start, populated with their respective tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me.  I'm running 5.0.375.55 beta.  If you go into Options -> Basics -> On startup, there is an option to "Reopen the pages that were open last".

I just ran a test of two chrome windows, each with multiple tabs open.  When I exited via the exit menu option (the wrench icon), both windows full of tabs opened when I next launched chrome.

If you forget to exit that way and instead X out of chrome, you can still get the tabs back.  When you open a new tab, there should be an entry for recently closed tabs.  If you closed a window, it should be listed as "X tabs".  Clicking the link should reopen the window with the correct tabs.